# What is the Taylor series of a square root?

Tags: calculus

I recently learned more about Taylor series, what I called infinite polynomials, and decided to find the Taylor series of $\sqrt{x}$. Of course, because $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x}$ at $x=0$ is undefined, I am actually asking about the Taylor series of $\sqrt{x+1}$. I have *found* the Taylor series for this, kinda. It is $\sum_{n=0}^∞\left(\left(\prod_{m=1}^n\left(1.5-m\right)\right)\cdot\frac{x^n}{n!}\right)$. My real question is: Can this be made smaller?

Comment: The OP is asking for the most "compact" closed form so I doubt the duplicate-target helps. Whether the inquiry is misguided is another issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the "smallest" representation I know of.

$$\sqrt{x+1} = \sum_{n\ge 0} \dbinom{\tfrac{1}{2}}{n} x^n$$

This is not strictly a Taylor series. It is actually the Binomial Expansion. It is still an infinite series. Is this what you are looking for?

Edit: Actually, looking at the series you calculated, these two representations should be the same.

Comment: It actually is a taylor series of $\sqrt{x}$ at $x=1$, or a taylor series of $\sqrt{x+1}$ at $x=0$

Answer (score 3):

There  is a general formula for the expansion of a binomial: for any $\alpha\in\mathbf R$, one has
$$(1+x)^\alpha=1+\alpha x+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2!} x^2+\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)}{3!} x^3+\dots +\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n+\dotsm,$$
where $\binom{\alpha}{n}$ is the *generalised binomial coefficient*:
$$\binom{\alpha}{n}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\dots(\alpha -n+1)}{n!}.$$
This *binomial series* converges for all $|x|<1$.

For $\sqrt{1+x}=(1+x)^{1/2}$, it begins with
$$\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac x2 -\frac18x^2+\frac1{16}x^3-\frac5{128} x^4+\dotsm$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{1+x}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}{n}x^n\\
&=1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\binom{2n}{n}\,x^{n+1}}{(n+1)\,2^{2n+1}}\\
&=1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n+1}}\,C_n\,x^{n+1}
\end{align}
$$
Where $C_n$ are the [Catalan Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).